# Magento 2 : How to solve a message "Recoverable Error: Object of class"?

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, helper

I've created a simple helper override, with just a constructor method using a **var dump**.

When I try to access the contact page I see a message error like that below.

I didn't implement anything just a simple override, I have certain that the structure it's right, I just call the helper in the contact `form.phtml`, when I call other helpers it's working well. So I guess that it's an external issue with that module.

**Message:**

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Recoverable Error: Object of class Vendor\Override\Helper\Infortis\AddToLinks could not be converted to string in app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml on line 10
```

How can I solve?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when you have another override in that same helper like you are doing.

Try to find another module that it's doing the override checking in the `di.xml`.